# How do I represent the "repeated" hour during the transition back to Standard time using JodaTime?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

On Nov 6, 2016, there will be two 01-02 hours:

- 01:00:00 - 01:59:59 Daylight time then
- 01:00:00 - 01:59:59 Standard time

Standard time can be represented like this:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

public void DoSomething() {
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
    localDateTime = formatter.withZone(tz).parseDateTime("2016-11-06 02:01:00");
}
```

Representing Daylight time during the 01-02 hour before the transition back to Standard time, however, has been challenging. It appears that the business rule associated with parsing an ambiguous time is "default to Standard time":

```
//Ambiguous time, treated as Standard
DateTime ambiguousTime = formatter.withZone(tz).parseDateTime("2016-11-06 01:59:00");
```

I am unsure how to override this rule, and differentiate between Daylight and Standard. This is at an API boundary, and I can have clients supply almost anything. I would think that an offset along with a time zone, should be sufficient to disambiguate in these corner cases, which appears to be [how NodaTime does it](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime__ctor_2.htm)?

If this is the "right" way to do this using Joda time, could someone provide an example? If there's another way, I'm open to doing it that way, too.

Comment: not sure I understand, yes you have ambiguous times, because you haven't specified the timezone in your string representation. How do you know they are newyork times but not know the utc offset?

Comment: An IANA timezone + datetime is insufficient to determine an exact instant for two hours, one day of the year: the day the clock goes backward from Daylight Saving to Standard Time. Imagine it's 1:54am on Nov 6 in America/New_York. Is that UTC-4 or UTC-5? You can't know without more information, because the first time through the 1-2 hour, it's UTC-4, the second time through, it's UTC-5. (1-2 simply doesn't exist during the Spring jump.) I can have a client supply what it wants that time to mean (-4 or -5) as part of the service call, but I'm unsure of how to make use of it within JT once I do.

Comment: I believe there is a fromUTC method? If you know the offset then you could use that. But I would try adding the offset to your string first

Comment: Yeah, it seems that is one workaround: adding the offset as part of the input time does make Daylight(UTC-4) vs Standard(UTC-5) representable. I wasn't able to find a way to make it representable without including the offset in the parser. I suppose that's fine, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to make Daylight time representable, except via the formatter, by including the offset as part of the parsed string.

Here's an example.

```
private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");

public void DoSomething() {
    String daylightWithOffset = "2016-11-06 01:56:00 -0400";
    DateTime daylightUnambiguous = formatter.withZone("America/New_York").parseDateTime(daylightWithOffset);
    System.out.println(daylightUnambiguous);    //2016-11-06T01:56:00.000-04:00

    String standardWithOffset = "2016-11-06 01:56:00 -0500";
    DateTime standardUnambiguous = formatter.withZone("America/New_York").parseDateTime(standardWithOffset);
    System.out.println(standardUnambiguous);    //2016-11-06T01:56:00.000-05:00
}
```

Under the hood, both of these have the correct UTC time representations, and they both have the proper time zones associated with them (`America/New_York`). Displaying them as local time both displays `01:56`, which is the expected and desired behavior.